# sysrq-g wont break kernel

Tags: kernel-module, kgdb

I am trying to setup linux kernel module debugging, using two machines - target and host. On target machine, I have compiled and installed a 3.5.0 kernel with `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ=y` flag and other flags for over the serial console debugging.

When I want to break the kernel to attach remote gdb, I use

```
$ echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

But above command is not breaking the kernel.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq"
```

Above command is returning 1, hence magic sysrq keys are enabled. Even "echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger" is working and rebooting the machine. Can anybody please point out what I may be missing?

Thanks

Comment: And your kernel parameters are correct? See https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kdb/EnableKGDB.html.

Comment: I have used "kgdboc=ttyS0,115200 vmalloc=256MB" as boot params. I have also tried without vmalloc but still doesn't work. I have referred kernel.org

Comment: I would try with kgdbwait parameter. If it does not even stop with that, then you probably missed something when configuring.

Comment: ok my bad, when i checked using multimeter, turns out that the cable i was using was not null modem cable. once i switched the cable, it worked.

Comment: @NaveenRawat how did you verify this?

Answer (score 5):

You have first configure your target kernel as follows

```
CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_KGDB=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y (here I am using serial port for kgdb) 
CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ= y (for sysrq functions).
```

Now compile kernel with imx6 configuration file.
Boot the target with this compiled kernel.You have to tell tell target which serial port you are going to use for kgdb pupose.In my case I am using the same console port for kgdb also.This settings you can do either through kernel parameters or via sysfs entry.For  imx6 sabrelite board,I am using ttymxc1 for console.This will change depending on your target

1. As a kernel parameter
   Add the following parameter to bootargs

   kgdboc=/dev/ttymxc1,115200 to your arguments.
2. If you are using sysfs entry, do like this

```
echo /dev/ttymxc1,115200 > /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc
```

Since same serial port is used for both the console and debugging, we use agent proxy. Through agent proxy we get the target console as well as we do the debugging.
Source for compiling agentproxy is available at the following link
"https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/kernel/kgdb/agent-proxy/+/agent-proxy-1.96"
After compiling for host pc ,run it as follows

```
sudo ./agent-proxy 5550^5551 0 /dev/ttyS0,115200
```

Now you can see target terminal through telnet with this agentproxy support

```
sudo  telnet localhost 5550
```

(It is better to use this telnet instead of minicom where only this agent proxy support comes.)
When you want to start debugging, the target system has to enter debug mode from normal mode. We can do that in this way in target

```
echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Now it will enter debugger mode.
Now from host side run gdb on vmlinux of the arm compiled kernel.
Go to the corresponding kernel source directory and do like this

```
arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gdb ./vmlinux
```

Now it will show gdb terminal .From there you have to connect to target for kgdb,

```
$target remote /dev/ttyS0
```

In my case my host serial port is /dev/ttyS0.
Now it will get connected to target. Here after you can use gdb commands to debug the kernel.

You try this way.